# Calling a function with a click

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I am working on a simple social network. I am building it with PHP and MySQL. Users can post status updates just like on Facebook. I know how to use the INSERT INTO and SELECT FROM statements to input/output user statuses, but how would I go about having a button (an X) that when clicked it calls a function that holds a MySQL query that DELETES the post? Or one that edits the post? Is the way to do it a call to a function()?

Comment: This sounds like you should work through a basic mySQL/PHP tutorial first that covers these basics.

Comment: do you want to do it without the page refreshing, like facebook does?

Comment: agreed - work through a tutorial, then post if you hit a problem.

Comment: for the time being it is alright if the page refreshes.

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server. The button exists on the client. So you can't call a function directly.

You need to have a script that accepts some input over HTTP (since you want to *do* something, this should be an HTTP POST request, in PHP you can read that data via [`$_POST[]`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)). The script should sanity check the input, do any appropriate actions based on that input and make a response indicating success or failure.

The simplest way to have the browser make the request is to use a [`<form>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html). This also allows you to collect information you may need from the user.

To do it "just like on Facebook" (while following [best practises](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degredation_versus_progressive_enhancement)) you should use [JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills) to bind a [submit event listener](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript) to the form, then stop the default event and use [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to make the HTTP POST request instead (this is Ajax). Then you use [DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML) to update the information displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn AJAX to do that. With an Ajax call, you would capture the `click` event with JavaScript, and will post an AJAX request to a **PHP** script that will issue the corresponding `delete` sql statement to drop the post.